# Parsing iw wlan0 station dump output

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I know this is a similar question from other posts. But i would like to **parse iw wlan station dump** and save the Mac Address of the strongest station signal to a text file or maybe in python make it as a variable.

Compare Multiple Stations with different signals (lower number mean strongest). i need to compare signals from this multiple stations and pick the mac address of the strongest signal (ex. -55 vs -60)

```
# awk '/Station/{val=$2;next} /signal/{sub(/^ +/,"");print "MAC Address: "val ORS $0;val=""}'

MAC Address: a8:83:02:cf:3d:e2
        signal:         -60 [-60] dBm
MAC Address: f4:60:e2:e2:2f:2e
        signal:         -55 [-55] dBm
```

from this i want to get the lowest number(strongest). just need to print only 1 station (mac address)
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBbqP.jpg)

--

Latest Code Result (selected signal doesn't match mac address)

```
# iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep -E 'Station|signal' //Reference
Station a8:8e:08:cf:1d:e9 (on wlan0)    <-------
        signal:         -28 [-28] dBm
Station f4:20:e2:a8:3f:3e (on wlan0)
        signal:         -55 [-55] dBm
# sudo iw dev wlan0 station dump | awk //Command
MAC Address: f4:20:e2:a8:3f:3e          <-------
        signal:         -27 [-28] dBm
```

Comment: Could you please post output of `sudo iw wlan0 station dump` in your post with code tags and let us know then?

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13 i just posted the result. thank you

Comment: I am not seeing `Frequency   Signal      Encryption` strings in that output then how your code will work if these strings are not there in it, could you please do let me know which field(with their names) you are interested to get them in output? eg---> `tx packets` etc

Comment: i tried to get Station and Signal only. please dont mind the freq and etc.. i have problem figuring out how to display Station (mac address) with Signal ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT5:*** Since you have NOT told that mac address could be found either after string `station` or after string `MAC Address` so my previous codes were looking only for `station` string now I have added logic to check both. Also considering that `<-------` is only for understanding purposes and not present in Input_file.

```
awk '
/Station/{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  a[++count]=$2
  value=""
  next
}
/MAC Address/{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  a[++count]=$NF
  value=""
  next
}
/signal/{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  value=sig_value<$2?$0:prev?prev:$0
  sig_value=$2
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
     split(b[i],array,"[[:space:]]+")
     max=max==""?array[2]:max
     ip_max=max>array[2]?ip_max:a[i]
     max=max>=array[2]?max:array[2]
     va[max]=max>=array[2]?va[max]?va[max]:b[i]:b[i]
  }
  print "MAC Address: "ip_max ORS va[max]
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT4:*** As per OP to get LOWEST signal value, could try following then.

```
awk '
/Station/{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  a[++count]=$2
  value=""
  next
}
/signal/{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  value=sig_value<$2?$0:prev?prev:$0
  sig_value=$2
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
     split(b[i],array,"[[:space:]]+")
     max=max==""?array[2]:max
     ip_max=max>array[2]?ip_max:a[i]
     max=max>=array[2]?max:array[2]
     va[max]=max>=array[2]?va[max]?va[max]:b[i]:b[i]
  }
  print "MAC Address: "ip_max ORS va[max]
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT3:***(This solution is to get HIGHEST signal value)Adding 4th answer now since OP again changed requirement and told out of all stations best signal value should come then try following.

```
awk '
/Station/{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  a[++count]=$2
  value=""
  next
}
/signal/{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  value=sig_value>$2?$0:prev?prev:$0
  sig_value=$2
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(value){
    b[count]=value
  }
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    split(b[i],array,"[[:space:]]+")
    ip_max=max<array[2]?ip_max:a[i]
    max=max<array[2]?max?max:array[2]:array[2]
    va[max]=b[i]
  }
  print "MAC Address: "ip_max ORS va[max]
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** OP says it may have multiple `signal` strings in Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
awk '
/Station/{
  if(val && value){
    print "MAC Address: "val ORS value
    val=value=""
  }
  val=$2
  next
}
/signal/{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  value=sig_value>$2?$0:prev?prev:$0
  sig_value=$2
  prev=$0
}
END{
  print "MAC Address: "val ORS value
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed requirement and asked to get strongest signal's value then following may help here.(Here considering that `mac address` value will come only 1 time but signal's values will be multiple and we need to choose best one out of them).

```
awk '
/Station/{
  val=$2
  next
}
/signal/{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  value=sig_value>$2?$0:prev?prev:$0
  sig_value=$2
  prev=$0
}
END{
  print "MAC Address: "val ORS value
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '/Station/{val=$2;next} /signal/{sub(/^ +/,"");print "MAC Address: "val ORS $0;val=""}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184242/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-parsing-iw-wlan0-station-dump-output).